# visual studio code indentation after multiline function call

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code on Mac for C++ coding. One thing I notice is that if I call a function as follows:

```
funcCall(img,
         param_1,
         param_2);
         <- Current new line
<- Expected new line
```

Now when I press `Enter` the new line gets indented under `param_2` rather than get aligned with the `funcCall` and I normally have to press backspace a few times to get the cursor where I want it.

I am not sure which VS Code setting I need to modify to get the indentation work as I want.